# Writing MASM functions for c++ program

Tags: c++, c, assembly, masm

Can anyone point me to a good tutorial on / explain the basics of writing functions in assembly and then linking them into a c++ program?

Comment: inline assembly...  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C

Comment: @neagoegab Inline assembly is something else. It doesn't involve somehow telling the assembler that a certain point should be exported as a function entry point, or writing a c++ function prototype for an assembly function, or assembling into a format usable by the linker, or worrying about calling conventions, or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are couple of articles you can use:
http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/c-prog-mixing.html

http://lavernasbrute.blogspot.com/2010/02/calling-assembly-functions-in-c.html

just google 'assembly functions in C'.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add `.asm` files to a project and implement the required functionality inside them. When compiled, you'll get a standard `.obj` file corresponding to the assembly source file.
2. Declare your functions as `extrn` in the assembly source code to allow calling them from other linkage units.
3. In your `C++` code declare the external `asm` funcs as `extern` and with `C` linkage (`extern "C"`) - this is the assembly convention of calling and you must comply.

Comment: Also be careful with the calling conventions - best to specify those explicitly in this case I think.

Comment: @Voo it's in the answer (par. 3)

Comment: I don't mean C linkage, but the actual calling convention, e.g. stdcall, when defining the function.

Comment: In assembly source code?

Comment: Well if you pass arguments into the asm functions you'll still have to follow the right calling convention and there's no compiler that actually makes sure that its implicit default matches the one you implemented by hand.

Comment: ah, you're talking about the input params to assembly code. good point

Answer (score 0):

Check [this one](http://www.deconflations.com/2011/masm-assembly-in-visual-studio-2010/), it should be helpful

Comment: I saw that. It is about writing whole assembly programs in Visual Studio, not about writing just a function and calling it from c/c++

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline ASM, but may not support some instruction. But enough at all., As you know, some CRT function is implemented by inline ASM.

```
__asm
{
    emit ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: I know about inline ASM. That is not what I need, since it doesn't support x64 assembly.